# Thingsboard 3.2.2 Latest Telemetry and dashboard empty when domain https

Tags: thingsboard

Hi I have installed thingsboard CE in my ubuntu server by followinng instruction in this https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/ubuntu/ . After the thingsboard installed, my domain still localhost:8080 and its working fine, I can post my JSON data to device by using Postman. After that, I have change my domain to http://mywebsite.com:8080 and all still working fine. After several days, i change it to https for security purpose and become https://mywebsite.com . But after changing it to https, When I publish the telemtry using Postmann, it doesn't appear in latest telemtry in Device. I already check the debug in the rule chain and it said success.
After that I check the logs and it said like this

```
2021-07-26 14:05:33,306 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-6] ERROR o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler - Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null
2021-07-26 14:05:33,359 [TB-Scheduling-1] INFO  o.t.server.actors.ActorSystemContext - Rule Engine JS Invoke Stats: requests [49] responses [49] failures [0]
2021-07-26 14:05:33,664 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-10] ERROR o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler - Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null
2021-07-26 14:05:34,795 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-5] ERROR o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler - Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null
2021-07-26 14:05:34,956 [sql-log-2-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - Queue-0 [TS] queueSize [0] totalAdded [17] totalSaved [17] totalFailed [0]
2021-07-26 14:05:35,066 [sql-log-2-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - Queue-0 [TS Latest] queueSize [0] totalAdded [17] totalSaved [17] totalFailed [0]
2021-07-26 14:05:39,003 [sql-log-2-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - Queue-0 [Attributes] queueSize [0] totalAdded [1] totalSaved [1] totalFailed [0]
2021-07-26 14:05:40,254 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-9] ERROR o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler - Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null
2021-07-26 14:05:40,489 [queue-scheduler-11-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.q.u.DefaultTbApiUsageClient - Report statistics for: 1 tenants
```

Why the latest telemetry is empty after i change it to https? and whats the meaning of this?

> Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null

Answer (score 0):

After trying again, I find that the error is WebSocket error event where WebSocket connection to https://mywebsite.com failed. Still don't know what happen and how to check the connection of the webSocket in thingsboard?

Answer (score 0):

How do you realize the HTTPS connection? By a reverse proxy? Then you must take care that Websocket connections to /api/ws are correctly handled. For Apache, I have explained it in [Telemetry does not show up in Thingsboard device dialog ("Hello world" tutorial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74202906/telemetry-does-not-show-up-in-thingsboard-device-dialog-hello-world-tutorial)